# Ajax ответ - формировать таблицы на сервере или клиенте?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть у меня небольшая системка по учету слонов, слоны синие, красные, их адреса, имена и тд. Пользователь может смотреть списки слонов по городу, по цвету, редактировать все это. В общем табличные данные. В данный момент html-код формируется php-скриптом POST-запросами, но ради практики переношу на ajax.

Как разумнее формировать таблицы? Предполагаю такие **варианты**:

1) формировать html на сервере, тогда ajax {dataType:html} и вывести на страницу;

2) ajax {dataType:json}, получаем, распарсиваем, средствами js формируем таблицу. Но тогда в js будет каша, хотя туда никто не смотрит.

Допданные: нагрузки никакой нет, пофиг где будет выполняться.

Comment: Шаблонизацию лучше держать в одном месте. Если все генерируете на серевере, то и AJAX'ом проще отдавать HTML. Если хотите комбинированный вариант -- смотрите на шаблонизаторы, работающие как на сервере так и на клиенте (например mustache)

Comment: Я бы выбрал второй вариант. Мне кажется он более гибкий.

Comment: В наше время с реактом и ангуляром, лучше получать данные и шаблонизировать их на клиенте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Теория**

*Всегда* лучше гонять между сервером и клиентом только данные.
Все что можно делать на клиенте → делаем на клиенте.
Если позволяет время и желание, я бы действительно используя [MVC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Modern_web_app_architecture/MVC_architecture).
Поддерживать потом будет легче, да и новые знания и навыки никто не отменял.

На самом деле, даже на `vanilla js` никакой каши не будет, если правильно подходить к делу, [например](http://jsfiddle.net/7MRx6/338/)

**Практика**

1. У вас горит проект → пишем говнокод, как в вашем первом варианте
2. Проект не горит → делаем как описано в *теории*

Comment: Так большинство современных cms делают по первому варианту. точнее все, о которых мне известно.